# "empty block data" when starting orderer using Hyperledger Bevel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to finalise the tutorial and videos on the Demo network for Hyperleger bevel: https://blockchain-automation-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted.html

Init jobs for both test orgnizations seem to work ok (I also checked that logs show no error):

```
baf-demo ➤ kubectl get pod --all-namespaces                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  git:local
NAMESPACE          NAME                                           READY   STATUS             RESTARTS      AGE
flux-local         helm-controller-64b885475c-t9cdr               1/1     Running            0             41m
flux-local         image-automation-controller-75df8b8c4c-zj7tf   1/1     Running            0             41m
flux-local         image-reflector-controller-6bf9d95c94-qtcwg    1/1     Running            0             41m
flux-local         kustomize-controller-59f76cdfb5-ngvnh          1/1     Running            0             41m
flux-local         notification-controller-66c494d7d7-8rq5p       1/1     Running            0             41m
flux-local         source-controller-6587d6ff7-9x76n              1/1     Running            0             41m
kube-system        coredns-5d78c9869d-lv2xm                       1/1     Running            0             54m
kube-system        etcd-minikube                                  1/1     Running            0             55m
kube-system        kube-apiserver-minikube                        1/1     Running            0             55m
kube-system        kube-controller-manager-minikube               1/1     Running            0             55m
kube-system        kube-proxy-n2tds                               1/1     Running            0             54m
kube-system        kube-scheduler-minikube                        1/1     Running            0             55m
kube-system        storage-provisioner                            1/1     Running            0             55m
manufacturer-net   ca-757b68b6cc-bn2rj                            1/1     Running            0             31m
manufacturer-net   ca-tools-5c9db7fcd7-mn5sq                      2/2     Running            0             23m
manufacturer-net   manufacturer-cacerts-job-d4nd5                 0/1     Completed          0             32m
manufacturer-net   manufacturer-vaultkubenertes-job-c6lsc         0/1     Completed          0             36m
manufacturer-net   peer0-0                                        0/3     Pending            0             22m
supplychain-net    ca-85d8848f7f-nhsx5                            1/1     Running            0             32m
supplychain-net    ca-tools-75b55fcfd4-2b97r                      2/2     Running            0             25m
supplychain-net    orderer1-0                                     1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   9 (44s ago)   22m
supplychain-net    supplychain-cacerts-job-6k65f                  0/1     Completed          0             33m
supplychain-net    supplychain-vaultkubenertes-job-x5j4n          0/1     Completed          0             37m
vault              vault-0                                        1/1     Running            0             54m
```

As you can see in that pod list, orderer1-0 is in CrashLoopBackOff state with the following log (no errors in the init containers for that deployment, kafka-healthcheck and certificates-init) but:

```
    baf-demo ➤ kubectl logs orderer1-0 -n supplychain-net                                                                                                                                                                                                                        git:local
    Defaulted container "orderer1" out of: orderer1, grpc-web, kafka-healthcheck (init), certificates-init (init)
    2023-07-26 13:09:12.654 UTC [localconfig] completeInitialization -> WARN 001 General.GenesisFile should be replaced by General.BootstrapFile
    2023-07-26 13:09:12.654 UTC [localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 002 Kafka.Version unset, setting to 0.10.2.0
    2023-07-26 13:09:12.654 UTC [orderer.common.server] prettyPrintStruct -> INFO 003 Orderer config values:
        General.ListenAddress = "0.0.0.0"
        General.ListenPort = 7050
        General.TLS.Enabled = true
        General.TLS.PrivateKey = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/crypto/tls/server.key"
        General.TLS.Certificate = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/crypto/tls/server.crt"
        General.TLS.RootCAs = [/var/hyperledger/orderer/crypto/tls/ca.crt]
        General.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
        General.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
        General.TLS.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 0s
        General.Cluster.ListenAddress = ""
        General.Cluster.ListenPort = 0
        General.Cluster.ServerCertificate = ""
        General.Cluster.ServerPrivateKey = ""
        General.Cluster.ClientCertificate = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/crypto/tls/server.crt"
        General.Cluster.ClientPrivateKey = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/crypto/tls/server.key"
        General.Cluster.RootCAs = [/var/hyperledger/orderer/crypto/tls/ca.crt]
        General.Cluster.DialTimeout = 5s
        General.Cluster.RPCTimeout = 7s
        General.Cluster.ReplicationBufferSize = 20971520
        General.Cluster.ReplicationPullTimeout = 5s
        General.Cluster.ReplicationRetryTimeout = 5s
        General.Cluster.ReplicationBackgroundRefreshInterval = 5m0s
        General.Cluster.ReplicationMaxRetries = 12
        General.Cluster.SendBufferSize = 10
        General.Cluster.CertExpirationWarningThreshold = 168h0m0s
        General.Cluster.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 0s
        General.Keepalive.ServerMinInterval = 1m0s
        General.Keepalive.ServerInterval = 10s
        General.Keepalive.ServerTimeout = 20s
        General.ConnectionTimeout = 0s
        General.GenesisMethod = "file"
        General.GenesisFile = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block"
        General.BootstrapMethod = "file"
        General.BootstrapFile = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block"
        General.Profile.Enabled = false
        General.Profile.Address = "0.0.0.0:6060"
        General.LocalMSPDir = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/crypto/msp"
        General.LocalMSPID = "supplychainMSP"
        General.BCCSP.ProviderName = "SW"
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.SecLevel = 256
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.HashFamily = "SHA2"
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.FileKeystore.KeyStorePath = ""
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.DummyKeystore =
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.InmemKeystore =
        General.Authentication.TimeWindow = 15m0s
        General.Authentication.NoExpirationChecks = false
        FileLedger.Location = "/var/hyperledger/production/orderer"
        FileLedger.Prefix = "hyperledger-fabric-ordererledger"
        Kafka.Retry.ShortInterval = 1s
        Kafka.Retry.ShortTotal = 30s
        Kafka.Retry.LongInterval = 5m0s
        Kafka.Retry.LongTotal = 12h0m0s
        Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.DialTimeout = 10s
        Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.ReadTimeout = 10s
        Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.WriteTimeout = 10s
        Kafka.Retry.Metadata.RetryMax = 3
        Kafka.Retry.Metadata.RetryBackoff = 250ms
        Kafka.Retry.Producer.RetryMax = 3
        Kafka.Retry.Producer.RetryBackoff = 100ms
        Kafka.Retry.Consumer.RetryBackoff = 2s
        Kafka.Verbose = true
        Kafka.Version = 0.10.2.0
        Kafka.TLS.Enabled = false
        Kafka.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
        Kafka.TLS.Certificate = ""
        Kafka.TLS.RootCAs = []
        Kafka.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
        Kafka.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
        Kafka.TLS.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 0s
        Kafka.SASLPlain.Enabled = false
        Kafka.SASLPlain.User = ""
        Kafka.SASLPlain.Password = ""
        Kafka.Topic.ReplicationFactor = 3
        Debug.BroadcastTraceDir = ""
        Debug.DeliverTraceDir = ""
        Consensus = map[SnapDir:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/snapshot WALDir:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/wal]
        Operations.ListenAddress = "0.0.0.0:9443"
        Operations.TLS.Enabled = false
        Operations.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
        Operations.TLS.Certificate = ""
        Operations.TLS.RootCAs = []
        Operations.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
        Operations.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
        Operations.TLS.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 0s
        Metrics.Provider = "disabled"
        Metrics.Statsd.Network = "udp"
        Metrics.Statsd.Address = "127.0.0.1:8125"
        Metrics.Statsd.WriteInterval = 30s
        Metrics.Statsd.Prefix = ""
        ChannelParticipation.Enabled = false
        ChannelParticipation.RemoveStorage = false
    2023-07-26 13:09:12.666 UTC [orderer.common.server] initializeServerConfig -> INFO 004 Starting orderer with TLS enabled
    2023-07-26 13:09:12.674 UTC [orderer.common.server] Main -> PANI 005 Failed validating bootstrap block: empty block data
    panic: Failed validating bootstrap block: empty block data

goroutine 1 [running]:
go.uber.org/zap/zapcore.(*CheckedEntry).Write(0xc0003b2580, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore/entry.go:230 +0x545
go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).log(0xc0000122b0, 0x11b3c04, 0x1029e5b, 0x25, 0xc0001cd8e8, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:234 +0x100
go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).Panicf(...)
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:159
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging.(*FabricLogger).Panicf(...)
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging/zap.go:74
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.Main()
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:118 +0x1c83
main.main()
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/cmd/orderer/main.go:15 +0x20
```

Is this problem due to peero0 in pending state yet?
If not, what can be missing or wrong in the Bevel configuration?
Also... I have configured Raft as consensus in Bevel network.yaml; why is any kafka check performed when the orderer node is setup?